# The better way of dealing with RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I would like to know which is more profficient way of placing children in RelativeLayout. There are two approaches of doing this:

1) Place the main view with absolute position (like `layout_centerInParent` or set margins/paddings correspondent to parent view) After that you add other views and set them attributes like `android:layout_above="@id/relative_view_id"` and place them below relative view. It is not good way because your views hierarchy in xml does not match to what you see in preview.

2) You assign to children of RelativeLayout attributes with absolute id `android:layout_above="@+id/relative_view_id"` (**+ appeared**). It provides the correct views order in xml. **BUT** when you looking for declaration of view with `relative_view_id` from java code (by pressing cmd+B) Android Studio suggests all the views where you declared @+id. In our case View with attribute `android:layout_above="@+id/relative_view_id"` will also appear in search results.

What is your way of placing Views in RelativeLayout?

Comment: Obviously, **1** (`@id/`). Anticipated referral (`@+id/`) introduces overhead.

Comment: @BobMalooga  #Big Man on Campus  indeed indeed

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Yessir... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**android:layout_above**

> Positions the bottom edge of this view above the given anchor view ID.
>   Accommodates bottom margin of this view and top margin of anchor view.

For your question I would prefer **No 1** way .

```
android:layout_above="@id/relative_view_id"
```

Its refer the already generated ***id*** (*relative_view_id*) .